# Send Multiple Email in PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am having trouble in sending multiple emails using phpmailer. If I send to only 1 email, the email can be send without any error. Tried to search and did a testing but with failed results. May someone check what did I do wrong, below are the codes.

I am using `GET` to send the data to page `mail.php` for processing the mail. Below are my coding for the get link,

```
//php and mySQL coding to select email from db
$emailKJ_string = implode(",",$emailKJ);
<iframe style="border:0;" src="http://www.ktmparking.com.my/staff/mail.php?emailKJ[]=<?php echo $emailKJ_string;?>&nama=<?php echo $nama;?>"></iframe>
```

The user email is taken from a database. Below are the codes for my mail.php for the PhpMailer processing,

```
if(isset($_GET['nama'])){
    $nama=$_GET['nama'];
}
require '../staff/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = '*my_host_name*';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = '*myusermane*';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '*mypassword*';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                  // TCP port to connect to 
$mail->setFrom('info@ktmparking.com.my', 'HR-KTMBCP');
$to=explode(",",$_GET['emailKJ']);
foreach($to as $emails)
{
    $mail->AddAddress($emails);
}
//other codes for phpmailer
```

This is the error that I recieved,

> ```
> Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /home/ktm10001/public_html/staff/mail.php on line 22
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/ktm10001/public_html/staff/mail.php on line 23
> Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: You must provide at least one recipient email address.
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you separate emails with coma – just remove brackets:

```
emailKJ=<?php echo $emailKJ_string;?>
```

If you want to pass array through URI (and don't do explode in mail.php) – you should pass each email address in this way:

```
emailKJ[]=first@email.com&emailKJ[]=second@email.com&emailKJ[]=third@email.com...
```

Comment: thanks for the details. Will try to remove the `[]` and give the update

Answer (score 1):

you are sending array not string here.

see http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp

try this as `$_GET['emailKJ']` is array of emails

```
$to = $_GET['emailKJ'];
```

Instead of

```
$to=explode(",",$_GET['emailKJ']);
```

Comment: thanks for the details. I tried that but now got this error `2016-02-21 04:42:47 Invalid address: (addAnAddress to): kamran@ktmparking.com.my,khairulamran.nazri@gmail.com Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: You must provide at least one recipient email address.`

Comment: what is value of echo $emailKJ_string;  ?

Comment: just use _emailKJ_ instead of _emailKJ[]_ in url and no change in your previous code, try this

Comment: value of echo are eg; email1@gmail.com,email2@gmail.com,email3@gmail.com. I will try to remove the [] and will update the result